# NMI from external clustering

Tags: r, igraph

I want to compare the Normalized Mutual Information of different clustering solutions. Those clustering solutions come from different sources but I want to compare them with NMI.

I know there is the `compare()` function in `igraph`, but that needs the objects to be of class communities.

From the help file: Compares community structures using various metrics.

Now is there an *as.communities* or *as_communities* command or some way to get the NMI of two matrices?

This throws an error:

```r
karate <- graph.famous("Zachary")

igraph_community <- cluster_infomap(karate)

v <- as.vector(V(karate))
external <- cbind (v, c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,14)) )

compare(igraph_community,external, method = "nmi" )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compare` looks for either a communities object or a vector. Right now, you are sending it a 2 x n matrix in `external`. Subset it to just the vector of community membership:

```
compare(igraph_community,external[,2], method = "nmi" )
[1] 0.3105313
```